# Score calculation difference while solving vs. explaining the score

Tags: optaplanner

I have a DRL using HardMediumSoftScore, and have found that in some cases there is a difference in score result while calculating and afterwards while explaining the score.

```
SolverFactory<Problem> solverFactory=solverFactory.cloneSolverFactory();
Solver<Problem> solver = requestSolverFactory.buildSolver();
Problem solved = solver.solve( problem );
```

At the end of this snippet, the Solver logs some kind of score, e.g:

```
Solving ended: time spent (100648), best score (-339hard/0medium/0soft)...
```

After the above snippet, I immediately have:

```
ScoreDirector<Roster> scoreDirector = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory().buildScoreDirector();
scoreDirector.setWorkingSolution( solved );
scoreDirector.calculateScore();

for( ConstraintMatchTotal constraintMatchTotal : scoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals() )
{
        LOG.debug( "{} {} {}",constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintName(),constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintMatchCount(), constraintMatchTotal.getScoreTotal() );
}
```

Here hard scores always match, but sometimes there are also medium scores in the explanation, which are not there at the end of solving, like:

```
hardConstraint 3 -339hard/0medium/0soft
mediumConstraint 14 0hard/-1582medium/0soft
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In the solver config, turn on `environmentMode` `FULL_ASSERT` (or `FAST_ASSERT`) and let it run long enough. I suspect you 'll get a score corruption exception. Fix that first.
(Read the score corruption error message analysis a couple of times to understand it.)

Comment: You are right, it fails in CH phase with "2 ConstraintMatches missing", referencing the same rule in my DRL. I have read it about 10 times, but I must day, I have no clue, what is wrong.

Comment: Could it be, that OptaPlanner does not work correctly, if the getter and setter methods are not plain Java, but are generated by Roo (AspectJ) or by Lombok? If I remove the offending rule, I am getting strange IllegalStateExceptions at the end of the CH Phase saying, that and entity is not part of the Solution (was not added to ScoreDirector).

Comment: Maybe - the Roo or Lombok stuff might indeed cause trouble for the default SolutionCloner - although it's the first time I would hear about this. Can your remove them from the reproducer and see if it still reproduces?

Comment: I am still getting "the entity was never added to this ScoreDirector"...

Comment: I haven't heard of a common user pitfall that yields that excepton. It could be a number of things. Basically the error probably says that the is a "variable has been modified" event on an instance that wasn't in the working solution entities list to begin with.

Comment: As it turned out, I had several issues. For one part, I had a mismatching implementation of compareTo/equals, but, most importantly, I tried to call java methods which work on the PlanningVariables. But these methods were of course not called by Drools, as from a Drools perspective there was no change on LHS. This caused the biggest problem. I am right now trying to write an IncrementalCalculator for my problem domain. After 4 days I must say, it is not for the faint of heart. Question: Is it on intention that ConstraintMatch does not implement equals and hashCode but does implement compareTo?

Comment: I haven't had a need yet for equals/hashcode for ConstraintMatch or ConstraintMatchTotal, but it does sound like a good feature request. [Create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) with a good use case and I 'll consider it.